# Tensorflow serving over https

Tags: tensorflow, https, tensorflow-serving

I need to configure tensorflow serving to work over https/ssl for the REST API.

Currently I am running the model as

./tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=9000 --model_name=t2v.pb --model_base_path=/apps/tfmdl_out/mdl1/

It works over http locally, but due to VPN rules remote requests have to go through SSL.

How can I serve the REST API over SSL?

Thanks!

Ilya

Answer (score 2):

Use [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com) (a web server) as a proxy to listen on HTTPS, and internally ask Nginx to do the HTTP traffic in your network. See [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/) for more information on how to do this.